# What would someone have to know to build a GUI FLV Converter program for Windows?

Tags: video, encoding, flv

Just have no idea from where to start to roll out my own flv conveter to convert video to flv from other formats.

Comment: If my answer (or anyone's  answer) is useful for you, please a) up vote the answer, and/or b) mark an answer as *'accepted'*.  This is how we say 'thanks' on Stack Overflow

Comment: Ha! Ha! Detailed instruction but prominent suggestion. So is on the universe!

Answer (score 1):

This is *very* broad question.  It would help if you narrowed it down to specific areas.  But, some guesses:

- become familiar with [**FFmpeg**](http://ffmpeg.org/), the *de facto* standard open source video conversion utility.  It is a command line tool, and you can wrap your GUI around it.  You'll need to become somewhat of an expert on all the different options regarding audio and video bit rates, aspect rations, resolution (aka size), audio sampling frequencies, etc.
- become familiar with ***FLV file meta data issues*** (and how Flash players use the meta data)
- realize that FLV files days are numbered.  ***MP4/h264 is the future.***  Newer Flash players like them just so (as do most MP4 capable video players) and are frequently refered to as F4V files.
- select a GUI building tool/framework